# SMS receive only my android Apps , others will not receive

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I want to create an android application, which is received SMS only , not receive native Message apps . But I receive SMS , and native Message apps will receive .
My coce:..

SMSreceiver.java

```
public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{ 
 private final String TAG = "MYSMSRECEIVE"; 
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();     
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String strMessage = "";
        String strMsgBody = "";
        String strMsgSrc = "";
        if ( extras != null )
        {
            Object[] smsextras = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsextras.length; i++ )
            {
                SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsextras[i]);

                 strMsgBody = smsmsg.getMessageBody().toString();
                 strMsgSrc = smsmsg.getOriginatingAddress();
                 sb.append(smsmsg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                 sb.append(smsmsg.getDisplayMessageBody());
                strMessage += "SMS from " + strMsgSrc + " : " + strMsgBody; 

                Log.d("abcd", "estimateGlass estimateGlass::" +strMessage);

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ strMessage + ", message: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();                

            }
            int icon = R.drawable.inbox;
            CharSequence tickerText = strMsgSrc + ": " + strMsgBody;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
            CharSequence contentTitle = "New SMS Message";
            CharSequence contentText = sb.toString();
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
            notification.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        }

  }

  }
```

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sms.testreceiveservies"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.sms.testreceiveservies.SMSreceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".ServiceCommunicator"
        android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre KitKat 4.4, you can simply call abortBroadcast() but make sure you have a high priority on your receiver. Post KitKat you cannot do that, unless your are the default messaging chosen by user.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000"><!-- Or max int if you will -->
```

Comment: I have not used high priority

Comment: If you want to make sure your app gets notified then you should

Comment: I sure  app gets notified

Comment: Then as I mentioned abortBroadcast() will prevent other apps from being notified of sms received (unless they are watching the database), that's what you want, right?